# How to dump a range of revisions in svn via CMD in Windows 10

Tags: svn, cmd, windows-10, tortoisesvn

I am trying to create hundreds of individual dump files for an svn repo. So far I have this command to work off of which creates one single dump file for a specific revision.

```
svnrdump dump https://somesite.com/svn/project -r 1111 --incremental > Project_rev1111.dump
```

However, this is unfeasible for creating many revisions manually. I know I can  something like:

```
svnrdump dump https://somesite.com/svn/project -r 1111:1114 --incremental > Project_rev1111.dump
```

Which will display in the cmd prompt:

```
* Dumped revision 1111.
* Dumped revision 1112.
* Dumped revision 1113.
* Dumped revision 1114.
```

So it looks like it dumps all the files in the specified range, but only creates the file "Project_rev1111.dump"

Is there a way to "pipe" in each of these revisions individually into their own corresponding files by modifying the command so that there will be 4 files created instead of 1?

Comment: `for /L %R in (1111,1,1114) do svnrdump dump https://somesite.com/svn/project -r %R --incremental > Project_rev%R.dump`?

Comment: that worked, thanks! what do you call what you just did and where can i learn more? i don't know anything about cmd or cmd scripting. @aschipfl

Comment: It's called a `for` loop, and like almost every built-in command and utility, you can find out how it works by opening a Command Prompt window, typing the command name, adding the help option `/?`, and pressing the `[ENTER]` key. In this case that would be `for /?`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use a [`for` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) in order to run the `svnrdump` command separately for every applicable revision:

```cmd
for %R in (1111 1112 1113 1114) do svnrdump dump https://somesite.com/svn/project -r %R --incremental > Project_rev%R.dump
```

If you have got a continuous range of revisions, you can use a [`for /L` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_l.html) instead:

```cmd
for /L %R in (1111,1,1114) do svnrdump dump https://somesite.com/svn/project -r %R --incremental > Project_rev%R.dump
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this functionality was added since the OP posted their question, but the code in the question works for me (svnrdump version 1.14.0):

```
svnrdump dump https://somesite.com/svn/project -r 1111:1114 --incremental > Project_rev1111.dump
```

and you can specify a range up to the current revision using `HEAD`:

```
svnrdump dump https://somesite.com/svn/project -r 1111:HEAD --incremental > Project_rev1111.dump
```

My version of `svnrdump` did not seem to allow using dates which [apparently work for svnadmin dump](https://serverfault.com/questions/282131/how-can-i-use-a-batch-file-to-dump-only-the-last-few-weeks-revisions-in-svn).

```
svnadmin dump /path/to/repo/ -r {2011-05-20}:HEAD > /path/to/dumpfile
```

but maybe that functionality will get added one day, so worth checking.